# What are the first 4 nodes visited by Depth-first tree search from A to G?

Tags: search, data-structures, depth-first-search

I am reading the book titled Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach by Stuart Russell and Peter Norvig (4th edition) where he explained the difference between a DFS on graph search and on tree search. So the basic difference is that: tree search does not have an explored list to keep track of the visited nodes while graph search does. Keeping that in mind, I knew that the depth-first tree search will not terminate in this picture below, because node B will be expanded again and again. Now my question is what are the first 4 nodes by Depth-first tree search for the picture below if I want to go from A to G?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A tree is a directed acyclic graph with the restriction that a child can have only one parent. In that case, there's no reason to keep track of visited nodes because it's impossible to visit a node more than once.

I'll assume that the tree is not ordered and your "search" is actually a depth-first traversal that will stop when it encounters the target node.

The order in which nodes are visited depends on the way you write your algorithm. If you always visit the left node and its descendants before you visit the right node and its descendants, then the order is [A,B,C,D,E,G]. If you visit the right node before the left, then the order is [A,B,D,G].

If you're having trouble understanding why there's no need for a visited list, take a look into recursive tree traversal algorithms.